# Python - Auto add widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, tkinter

So I am currently trying to create a button on a GUI that will let the user generate a new entry field.
I have no idea how to do this. I'm guessing that it will require a lambda function, but apart from that, I have no idea.

Here's the basic code I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *

class prac:

    def autoAddWidget(self,frame,x,y):
        self.entryField = Entry(frame,text="Entry Field")
        self.entryField.grid(row=x, column=y)
        #lambda function? 

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master, width=60, height=50)
        frame.pack()

        x=1
        self.addWidgetButton = Button(frame, text="Add new widget", command=self.autoAddWidget(frame, x,0))
        self.addWidgetButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
        x+=1


root = Tk()
app = prac(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Would appreciate the help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing to the `command` argument result from the method `self.autoAddWidget(frame, x,0)` not method itself. You have to pass there a reference to a callable object, a function that will be called when the event occurs. Please check a [documentation](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm) next time before you ask the question.

Ok, I fixed the code, now it works:

```
from tkinter import *

class Prac:

    def autoAddWidget(self):
        self.entryField = Entry(self.frame,text="Entry Field")
        self.entryField.grid(row=self.x, column=0)
        self.x+=1

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master, width=60, height=50)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.x=1
        self.addWidgetButton = Button(self.frame, text="Add new widget", command=self.autoAddWidget)
        self.addWidgetButton.grid(row=0, column=0)


root = Tk()
app = Prac(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Been stuck on this for a long time. Also, thanks for not just the solution, but the documentation too.